# Setting up remote yum repositories (Rocky/Centos) in Google Artifacts Registry doesn't populate packages

Tags: registry, metadata, yum, artifacts

I've setup some remote yum repositories in our GAR.

If we explore the remote repository created, we see 'no files'.  If we verify via `gcloud artifacts files list --repository <repo>`, we can see that the yum metadata is present, but no packages are downloaded, so, yum/dnf makecache fails.

Is this a known issue with Remote yum repositories?  I know that the feature is in Preview, so, I imagine there's still some fixing, but if not, anyone knows how to trigger the process to start downloading the 'rpms'?

Trying to create a 'remote' yum repository to act as a mirror of rocky-8-{appstream,baseos,extras,powertools) repos and the same for centos.

If I create a local standard repository, and I upload the rpms from a mirror, it populates the packages correctly, but 'REMOTE_REPOSITORY' mode, doesn't